# kendo paging issue on ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

After an initial load, I am trying to filter the kendo grid using an ajax request because I am filtering based on many controls outside the grid. My request data is correct in newObj and the results I get from the server are correct.
I am using this code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Books/GetAll',
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(newObj),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (returnValue) {
        var grid = $('#kBooks').getKendoGrid();
        grid.dataSource.data(returnValue.GridData);
        **grid.dataSource.totalPages(returnValue.TotalCount);**
        grid.refresh();
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
    }
});
```

I get the proper data shown on the grid, but grid becomes no more pageable although I get returnValue.TotalCount as more than 1 page.
I just need to know how to set the total pages value on the grid after setting the data.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `totalPages` method can't set the total pages. You only need to set the total if the data source is configured for server paging. However in this case the data source needs to retrieve data by itself (using its transport configuration).

If you have not enabled server paging you don't need to set the total. The data source will page the available data (set via the `data` method).

If you have enabled server paging you need to change your implementation:

```
dataSource: {
  schema: {
    // Describe the response format
    data: "GridData",
    total: "TotalCount"
  },
  transport: {
    read: function(options) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'Books/GetAll',
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(newObj),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (returnValue) {
          // notify the data source that data has been received
          options.success(returnValue);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
        }
      }); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Atanans, Thanks for replying. But I am using the ajax method outside of the transport read. for e.g., on a button click outside the grid, I want to use this outside method to refresh the grid instead of the grids read function. How can I fix the paging now ?

Comment: I have answered that in my reply. If you use server paging you must use a custom transport. If you don't - you don't need to set the totals.

Comment: Hi @AtanasKorchev i have also kendo grid paging problem i'm loading my data from ajax everything looks fine but i cant paging or resizing grid ... here is my question maybe you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197713/kendo-ui-grid-paging-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment60033754_36197713