# Kendo UI Grid Paging is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In document ready i append div inside body and i am creating a kendo ui window and then inside that window append second div with creating kendo dynamic chart or kendo grid.

When i create this things i'm loading data from AJAX and shows grid normally, but paging and column resizing is not working

Can you help me on this situation?

Here my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '../Home/GetChartsAndInformations',
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
                    count = data.length;
                    $("body").append('<div class="chartWindow" id="chartWindow-' + i + '"><div id="chart-' + i + '"></div></div>');
                    var myWindow = $('#chartWindow-' + i).kendoWindow().getKendoWindow();
                    myWindow.setOptions({
                        width: data[i - 1].Width,
                        height: data[i - 1].Height,
                        actions: ["Pin","Maximize", "Close"],
                        position: {
                            top: data[i - 1].Ypos,
                            left: data[i - 1].Xpos
                        },
                        title: data[i - 1].ChartDescription
                    });
                    $("#chart-" + i).append(FillWindowWithCharts(i))
                }

            }
        });
    });

    function FillWindowWithCharts(number) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '../Home/QuerySelected',
            data: { id: number },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length != 0) {
                    if (data[0].ChartType == "grid") {
                        myData = data;
                        createGrid(data[0].Id);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (data[0].IsGroup) {
                            myData = {
                                data: data,
                                group: {
                                    field: data[0].GroupValue
                                },
                                sort: {
                                    field: data[0].SortValue
                                }
                            }

                            ToolTipTemplate = "#= dataItem.Value1 #: #= kendo.format('{0:N}',value)  #";

                        }
                        else {
                            myData = data
                        }

                        series = [{
                            field: data[0].SeriesField,
                            labels: {
                                visible: true
                            }
                        }];

                        categories = {
                            field: data[0].CategoryField
                        }
                        stackValue = data[0].IsStacked;
                        chartType = data[0].ChartType;
                        title = data[0].ChartDescription;

                        createChart(number);
                    }


                }
                else {
                     $("#chart-" + number).html("No Data in this interval!!");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function createGrid(number) {
        $("#chart-" + number).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: myData,
            resizable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh:true,
                pageSize: 5
            },
            columns: [
                { field: "Value1", title: myData[0].Series1, hidden: myData[0].Series1 == null ? true : false },
                { field: "Value2", title: myData[0].Series2, hidden: myData[0].Series2 == null ? true : false },
                { field: "Value3", title: myData[0].Series3, hidden: myData[0].Series3 == null ? true : false },
                { field: "Value4", title: myData[0].Series4, hidden: myData[0].Series4 == null ? true : false },
                { field: "Value5", title: myData[0].Series5, hidden: myData[0].Series5 == null ? true : false }
            ]
        });
    }

    function createChart(number) {
        $("#chart-" + number).kendoChart({
            theme: "metro",
            dataSource:myData,
            title: {
                text: title
            },
            legend: {
                visible: true,
                position: "bottom",
                labels: {
                    template: '#: chartType == "pie" ? dataItem.Value1 : chartType == "donut" ? dataItem.Value1 : text #'
                }
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: chartType,
                stack: stackValue
            },
            series: series,
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "{0}"
                }
            },
            categoryAxis: categories,
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}",
                template: ToolTipTemplate
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: do you get any error's in your console?

Comment: @Reddy no it doesnt show any error...

Comment: what is the use of `var grid = $("#chart-" + number).data("kendoGrid");` line in your function, you dont have the grid built at this point but you are trying to retrieve the data from it...

Comment: If you check the upper side in decument ready i'm appending '$("#chart-" + number)' this div and then i'm getting data in  FillWindowWithCharts and create grid in CreateGrid function ... I think that line looks like wrong extra line @Reddy

Comment: Yes it is extra line which does nothing, Remove it and see if it helps.

Comment: @Reddy I remove that line but its still same

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?? so that it might be easier to resolve the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107223/discussion-between-saulyasar-and-reddy).

Comment: Nothing suspicious in your code. Please prepare a Kendo UI Dojo or jsfiddle demo to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Here is my all code https://jsfiddle.net/Lk7vdtd7/  and this my dojo version with example data http://dojo.telerik.com/OHEYE/3 @AtanasKorchev I'm try to create dynamic grids and charts in one page this grids and charts inside windows when document ready i'm creating kendo window with number of my data then i draw my charts and grids

Comment: The dojo works for me - I can resize the grid columns and page: http://imgur.com/H8WfeUR

Comment: The intresting part of here i sent this dojo to understand what i do but in my code i'm using Ajax request i'm geting datas true but and grid is showing values but i cant do resizing or paging @AtanasKorchev I will try to send screencast for my problem

Comment: Sorry @AtanasKorchev i cant create a screencast but this is my problem and i dont understand why its not wroking but i read your shared article http://www.telerik.com/blogs/kendo-ui-open-sources-dynamic-linq-helpers and use datasource result now it returns 'cannot read property slice of undefined' here i can send you my all code in .net fiddler maybe you can catch some inside https://dotnetfiddle.net/DRieJS

Comment: That error means that the response returned by your service isn't the one expected. Refer to the readme of the Kendo DynamicLinq: https://github.com/kendo-labs/dlinq-helpers#usage 
By the way the dotnetfiddle doesn't run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107631/discussion-between-saulyasar-and-atanas-korchev).

Comment: I solved my problem myself  after 2 months later :) @AtanasKorchev thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i read some kendo dynamic grid data binding articles . I found way how to bind dynamically to grid [some blog example](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/kendo-ui-open-sources-dynamic-linq-helpers)

I give an example below

```
function createGrid(number,from,to) {
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        serverPaging: false,
        pageSize: 10,
        transport: { //With the transform i can connect data from ajax 
            read: {
                url: "../Home/QuerySelected",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { id: number, from: from, to: to } // I can pass parameter
            },
            parameterMap: function (options) {
                return JSON.stringify(options);
            }
        },
        schema: { // Please be carefull because if you forget schema grid can give different errors. You need to write schema Data and Total and put right place in datasource
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total"
        }
    },
    resizable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true
    },
    sortable: true,
    filterable: {
        extra: false,
        operators: {
            string: {
                startswith: "Starts with",
                contains: "Contains"
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "Value1", title: myData.Data[0].Series1, hidden: myData.Data[0].Series1 == null ? true : false },
        { field: "Value2", title: myData.Data[0].Series2, hidden: myData.Data[0].Series2 == null ? true : false },
        { field: "Value3", title: myData.Data[0].Series3, hidden: myData.Data[0].Series3 == null ? true : false },
        { field: "Value4", title: myData.Data[0].Series4, hidden: myData.Data[0].Series4 == null ? true : false },
        { field: "Value5", title: myData.Data[0].Series5, hidden: myData.Data[0].Series5 == null ? true : false }
    ]
});

$(':contains("No Data in this interval!!")').each(function () {
    $("#chart-" + number).html($("#chart-" + number).html().split("No Data in this interval!!").join(""));
});
```

Thanks!